# Change Date picker dialog theme

Tags: android, datepicker, styles

I have implement datepickerdialog and want to remove the background color of Cancel and Ok Button and change text color of those buttons. This is in androidx project.

[image]

```
public void displayCalendar(final TextView tv, final String myFormat) {
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
            str_date = sdf1.format(c.getTime());
            tv.setText(str_date);
            mListener.onDateSelected();
        }

    };
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(con, R.style.DatePicker, date, c
            .get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    datePickerDialog.setTitle("");
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

In styles-

```
<style name="DatePicker" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#377dff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1C5CD3</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#377dff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ? any code would have been much better :)

Comment: the same code works fine in other project. I have not made any change.

Comment: post your existing code and clarify what you want to achieve and what isn't working, that's what @Umair is trying to tell you

Comment: I want to remove background of Cancel and Ok button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as below

```
 Button btn_ok = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
 btn_ok .setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); //add your color
```

Comment: this helped me:
Button btn_ok = datePickerDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        btn_ok.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        btn_ok.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B7000000"));